# How to remove certain str with variable attatched?

Tags: python, list

```
import random

##player cards

player_cardsnum = 0
player_cards = []
while player_cardsnum < 7:
    card_colour1 = ["red", "green","yellow","blue","wildcard"]
    card_num1 = (random.randint(0,9))
    rand_value1 = (random.choice([[card_num1],"+4","+2"," *reverse*"," *skip turn*"])) 
    rand_colour1 = (random.choice(card_colour1))

    player_cards.append (str(rand_colour1) + " " + str(rand_value1))

    player_cardsnum += 1
    if player_cardsnum == 7:
        print ("these are your cards:")
        print (player_cards)
    while True:
        val = random.randint(0,6)
        num_wild = "wildcard [",val,"]"
        not_wildcard = "wildcard" + "[1]"  + "[2]" or  + "[3]"  + "[4]" or  + "[5]" or  + "[6]" or  + "[7]" or  + "[8]" or  + "[9]"

        if "wildcard  *skip turn*"in player_cards:
            player_cards.remove ("wildcard  *skip turn*")
            player_cardsnum -= 1
        elif "wildcard  *reverse*"in player_cards:
            player_cards.remove ("wildcard  *reverse*")
            player_cardsnum -= 1
        elif "wildcard +2"in player_cards:
            player_cards.remove ("wildcard +2")
            player_cardsnum -= 1
        elif not_wildcard in player_cards:
            print ("oof", player_cards)
            player_cards.remove (not_wildcard)
            player_cardsnum +=1

            print (player_cardsnum)

        break
```

I'm trying to delete all instances of "wildcard[int]" in player_cards, as such cards don't exist in uno. 
Been working on this for ages and to make it as simple as possible would be great. Help please?

Comment: you need to make a regex which have `wildcard` in it and then remove al those character

Comment: No need for regex, removing all that `startswith("wildcard [")` should be enough.